# Potential problems in adding a prehung exterior door to a shipping container?

Tags: doors, shipping-container

So far I've not found a door kit under $1400 plus shipping.  I can pick up a prehung exterior plain door for $100-$200.

Plan:

Cut the rough opening with an angle grinder with cuttoff disks.   Set the opening to use the "out" corregation.  Cut slightly larger than the door frame.

On the inside lip of the corrugation, screw a 2x4.  For the top, use a combination of 1x4, and fill pieces.

On the outside attach another 2x4.  It's attached, using screws from the inside. Bead of caulk, applied to edge of this 2x4 to keep water out. Again at the top I have to create some trapezoid shaped pieces to fit between the 2x4 and the "in" corrugations.

Top has Z flashing with the part attached to the can put in with gasketed screws and silicone seal.

Now I have a wood edge rough opening, and can mount my door normally.

Additional items:

- All wood on exterior is primed with wood preservative, and painted before use.
- Add some kind of porch for further weather protection.
- Hang door so it swings out.

---

Response to comment:

Use of caulk to slow water ingress into frame:

The key here is to keep the screws dry, and to not have a constantly wet face on the the interior of the built up wood.

In practice, I'd run the caulk on diagonal lines, moving  water to the surface.  Same construct as rain screening.  Maybe I need an actual chunk of of screen to act as a drainage plane.

Could use a bead of construction adhesive.  Or silicon seal.

Newer caulks are good in our climate for 15 to 25 years as exposed weather seals.

Welding:  I don't have the skills, or the welder.  Steel framed doors are much rarer on the used market.

Comment: I don't like the use of caulk for anything like this. It's going to fail quickly. You need flexible flashing of some sort if you want an actual seal.

Comment: Also the overall question is opinion-based so this might get closed. If you focus on specific concerns we can answer those.

Comment: Would you consider welding? A C or L profile, or square/rectangle tube, welded to the cut edge of the corrugated wall could provide a good rough opening.

Comment: "Is it reasonable" is subjective and off topic. Please revise to ask something specific. Doors are installed in steel buildings all the time. I'm not sure why this is any different.

Comment: Consider a steel angle over the opening instead of all that caulking and shaped wood. Toe up inside the container. Toe out below the corrugations to provide a shelf for catching water.